# Transform a correlated subquery into a join

Tags: sql, netezza, correlated-subquery

I want to express this:

```
SELECT
    a.*
    ,b.timestamp_col
FROM weird_data_source a
LEFT JOIN weird_data_source b
ON a.id = b.id
    AND b.timestamp_col = (
        SELECT
            MAX(sub.timestamp_col)
        FROM weird_data_source sub
        WHERE sub.id = a.id
            AND sub.date_col <= a.date_col
            AND sub.timestamp_col < a.timestamp_col
    )
```

A couple notes here about the data:

1. `date_col` and `timestamp_col` aren't representing the same thing.
2. I'm not kidding... the data is really structured like this.

But the subquery is invalid. Netezza cannot handle the `<` operator in the correlated subquery. For the life of me I cannot figure out an alternative. How could I get around this?

My gut is telling me this could potentially be done with a join, but I haven't been able to be successful at this yet.

There's a dozen or so similar questions, but none of them seem to get at handling this type of inequality.

Comment: Are lateral joins available on the netezza platform?

Comment: Can you use CTEs and the Row_Number() function with netezza?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, nope :(

Comment: @TabAlleman, yes, CTEs and windowing functions are available. I've tried using `dense_rank`, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @sagi, not at all. This has very little to do with comparison operators, and more about semantics of the database

Answer (score 1):

This should get you pretty close. You will get duplicate rows if there are two rows with the exact same `timestamp_col` that otherwise meet the criteria, but otherwise you should be good:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.some_other_columns,    -- Because we NEVER use SELECT *
    b.timestamp_col
FROM
    weird_data_source a
LEFT JOIN weird_data_source b ON
    a.id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN weird_data_source c ON
    c.id = a.id AND
    c.date_col <= a.date_col AND
    c.timestamp_col < a.timestamp_col
LEFT OUTER JOIN weird_data_source d ON
    d.id = a.id AND
    d.date_col <= a.date_col AND
    d.timestamp_col < a.timestamp_col AND
    d.timestamp_col > c.timestamp_col
WHERE
    d.id IS NULL
```

The query is basically looking for a matching row where no other matching row is found with a greater `timestamp_col` value - hence the `d.id IS NULL`. That column will only be `NULL` if no match is found.

Comment: Just a quick question, is the `and` after the first left join erroneous?

Comment: Yep, that was a copy/paste error. I'll correct it, thanks.

Comment: Accepting this, since the duplication should be able to be handled with a `select distinct`. `select *` was just saving space when typing out the problem ;)

Comment: Went ahead and tried implementing this, and it was producing a Cartesian join. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Hrm. Looking back at it, I'm not sure think that first join is unnecessary. I had left it in as a remnant of your original query, but I don't think that it applies here. Can you please try removing it and seeing if that fixes the issue? If it does then I'll edit my answer. This is why sample data and expected outcome helps... I could have already performed these test steps.